# how can i save jquery ui sortable order in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

i have `new_cats` table it contains `id, title, order` and i post data from the table like this

**php**

```
    <table>
    <tbody class="sort">
    <?php
    $select_newscats = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news_cats order by ord_show asc");

    while ($rows_newscats = $select_newscats->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $id_newscats          = $rows_newscats ['id'];
    $title_newscats       = $rows_newscats ['title'];
    $order_newscats       = $rows_newscats ['order'];
    ?>
    <tr class="trtable" id="item_<? echo $id_newscats; ?>">
    <td><? echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $title_newscats; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?
    }
    ?>
<button class="savesort"></button>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

and i have this jquery code to sortable table and trying to update order in database

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sort").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        }
    }).disableSelection();

$('.savesort').on('click', function () {
var aa = $(".sort").sortable("serialize", {
attribute: "id"
});

var s = {
"aa":aa
}

$.ajax({
data: s,
type: 'POST',
url: 'ajax/save_newscats_ord.php',
success:function(data){
    alertify.success(data);
  }
});
return false;
});

});
```

in this page `save_newscats_ord.php`i tried to save order but i don't get any data from jquery code i tried this code to get data

```
<?php
$list = $_post['aa'];
echo $list;
?>
```

how can i send data to php page and how can i save it in my database in order filed

Comment: Please provide some sample data. Since it will be the resulting HTML that is sorted, we need to see how the data is indexed and how the sort gets done. Can't get a sense of that from your example.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$_POST` (uppercase)?

Comment: The way you are generating table, the value of the variables will get overwritten. You need to put the table row generation code inside the while loop. I am not entirely sure if this is the cause of the problem in addition to what @A.O. mentioned.

Comment: @A.O. yeah sorry it's a mistake i make it right and i get data in array how can i save it on database

Comment: Never mind. Looks like the table generation code is correct.

Comment: @MahmoudSamy looks like you're using mysql, here is a great resource for inserting data http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your PHP code to reference the actual POST variable passed, change this line:

```
$list = $_post['aa'];
```

to

```
$list = $_POST['aa'];
```

Note that the variable names are case sensitive in PHP.